Start Regex at Specific Position
I have a regex that identifies any time there are 6 or more consecutive "^" characters. I am trying to edit it so that it ignores the first 100 characters of the string, making it so it only catches 6 consecutive "^" characters if it happens after the first 100 characters.
 [\^]{6,}

How can I edit this to make it work?
Edit: The suggested answer is grabbing from character 100 all the way to the match that occurs. I am only trying to capture the match. Not all of the characters proceeding it.

^.{100,}\^{6} or ^.{100,}?\^{6}

You can add a capturing group to use it later on like this: ^.{100}([\^]{6,}) and use it with \1.
